# Storing value in ECX register and using lower register CL to shift by that value?

Tags: assembly, x86

So I stored a variable into register ECX and wanted to use 'shrl %cl, %eax' to shift the value inside register EAX by the variable amount stored in ECX. I tried this but the shift does not occur. Do I need to store the variable inside the CL register and, if so, how would I do this because 'movl variable, %cl' does not work for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That should have worked.

Comment: For the 'movl variable, %cl' part, I am getting the error '%cl not allowed with movl'

Comment: Indeed it isn't allowed. What should have worked was your original code. Otherwise you can also use `movb variable, %cl`.

Comment: See the debugging and reference material links at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should have worked. You forgot to provide full reproducible test case, so here is mine:

```
1       movl $3, %ecx
(gdb) si
2       movl $0xaaaaaaaa, %eax
(gdb)
3       shrl %cl, %eax
(gdb)
4       nop
(gdb) p/x $eax
$1 = 0x15555555
(gdb) p/x 0xaaaaaaaa >> 3
$2 = 0x15555555
```

Also note that shift count is masked to 5 bits.

Comment: Thank you. I tried inputting variables into ECX and shifting with %cl and it worked. The program seems to have a different problem then.